# How to check if VT-X is enabled in BIOS?

Tags: virtualization, bios

How to check if VT-X is enabled in BIOS?
I have `vmx` in CPU flags, and no access to the BIOS.

(I need to install a KVM VM on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.1).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` and see if there is `vmx` (Intel) or `svm` for AMD based.

or Try [`dmidecode`](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) it should provide a lot of information about your BIOS settings.

From thier website:

> dmidecode is packaged for several Linux and BSD distributions (Debian, Gentoo, openSUSE and FreeBSD among others), either as a single package or included in a more generic tool set.

It should be on the repos of your distro, or installed on your system already.

**UPDATE:** I have found your question [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=55639) and [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-check-if-vt-is-enabled-in-the-bios), but I'm unable to verify whether the above commands are give you the BIOS configuration status, or just your CPU abilities.

Comment: I know to check cpuinfo, as I said. I saw thoses links but they give no useful info. There seems to be a solution.. for DOS! The BIOS Writer approach requires access to the BIOS (!) which I say I don't have.

Comment: dmidecode seems to not be very specific, and very hardware-dependent..  "dmidecode | grep -i virt" only finds CPU flags accessible in cpuinfo.